# Is the join() method in Thread guaranteed to work perfectly or it is also dependent on individual JVM?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

**Overview**

I was learning and working with Threads in java. I just began investigating the `join()` method. I understand that it lets the *current thread* and forces it to **wait** until the `thread.join()` call ends/dead/terminates.

Here is the code I tried to utilize to explore the functionality:

**ThreadJoinMain**

```
package com.threeadjoin.main;

import sun.nio.ch.ThreadPool;

public class ThreadJoinMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CustomThreadOne threadOne = new CustomThreadOne();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(threadOne);
        t1.setName("Thread 1");
        t1.setPriority(10);

        Thread t2 = new Thread(threadOne);
        t2.setName("Thread 2");

        /*Thread t3 = new Thread(threadOne);
        t3.setName("Thread 3");*/

        try{
            t1.join();
            //t2.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        //t3.start();

    }
}
```

**CustomThreadOne**

```
package com.threeadjoin.main;

public class CustomThreadOne implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
            System.out.println("Inside thread: " + 
Thread.currentThread().getName() + " value: " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Most of the time it is giving satisfactory result like this:

```
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 0
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 1
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 2
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 3
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 4
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 5
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 6
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 7
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 8
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 9
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 0
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 1
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 2
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 3
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 4
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 5
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 6
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 7
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 8
```

But, if I run this code continuously without making any changes or forcefully re-building it, sometimes (very few though) the output is coming like this:

```
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 0
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 0
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 1
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 1
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 2
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 2
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 3
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 3
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 4
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 4
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 5
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 5
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 6
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 7
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 8
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 6
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 9
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 7
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 8
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 9
```

OR this:

```
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 0
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 0
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 1
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 1
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 2
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 2
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 3
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 3
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 4
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 4
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 5
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 5
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 6
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 6
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 7
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 7
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 8
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 8
Inside thread: Thread 2 value: 9
Inside thread: Thread 1 value: 9
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: What do you think `Thread.join()` does? Because your code shows you don't seem to understand its use. Specifically, joining a thread before it has been started does nothing: a `join()` waits until the thread it's called on has stopped, given it hasn't started, it doesn't wait. Also: if you want sequential behavior, don't use additional threads.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So I changed my code to this.
put these two lines
 
t1.start();
t2.start(); 

before the try block but still repeated running giving different results.
Where am I making the mistake, please let me know.

Comment: And I repeat: if you want sequential behavior, don't use additional threads. And you still don't seem to understand what `join()` does. Using `t1.join()` just means that the current thread will wait until `t1` has stopped. `t1` and `t2` will still be able to run in parallel.

Comment: if you want sequential behavior, don't use additional threads - I am taking it as a suggestion surely but not solving my query.

you still don't seem to understand what join() does. - My first line syas, I am learning. 

Using t1.join() just means that the current thread will wait until t1 has stopped. t1 and t2 will still be able to run in parallel. --Are you sure ???
Thank you !

Comment: Please edit your question and describe what you think `t1.join()` does, so we know exactly where your misconception is and we can give you a good explanation.

Comment: Re, "...it lets the current thread and forces it to wait until..." There's a simpler way to say that:  "`t.join()` waits for `t` to terminate."  That one sentence says pretty much everything you need to know about `join()`.

Answer (score 2):

**Overview**

Great question! **Yes! It is guaranteed to work as intended, and does not depend on the JVM**. However, I see quite a few points of confusion in your source code so I will step through the semantics on `join()` with a similar application. Lets investigate the example below.

**Example Application**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create threads t1 -> t3
    Thread t1 = new Thread(threadOne);
    t1.setName("Thread 1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(threadOne);
    t2.setName("Thread 2");
    Thread t3 = new Thread(threadOne);
    t3.setName("Thread 3");

    //////////// Explanation 1 /////////////

    t1.start(); // Begin execution of t1
    t2.start(); // Begin execution of t2

    //////////// Explanation 2 /////////////

     try {
         t1.join(); // Force main thread to wait for t1
    //////////// Explanation 3 /////////////
         t2.join(); // Force main thread to wait for t2
    //////////// Explanation 4 /////////////

         t3.start(); // Begin execution of t3
         t3.join(); // Force main thread to wait for t3
    //////////// Explanation 5 /////////////
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Here, there are actually 4 threads present in this code: `main`, `t1`, `t2`, `t3`. The main thread is the starting thread that the application creates and utilizes to run the application.

**Explanation 1**

At this point, only 1 thread is executing: the `main` thread. Although `t1`->`t3` have been created, they have not begun execution.

**Explanation 2**

Here, we have started `t1` and `t2` so that there are 3 executing threads: `t1`, `t2`, and `main`.

**Explanation 3**

At the `t1.join()`, the `main` thread (or the *calling* thread) **waits** for the execution of `t1` to finish. Once it has finished, the `main` thread continues executing. At this point, `t2` was executing in parallel to the `main` and `t1`.

**Explanation 4**

The `main` thread again waits for execution to finish, but this time for `t2`. Once it has finished, the `main` thread is unblocked and continues.

**Explanation 5**

The `main` thread has begun `t3`s execution, and immediately waited for it to complete.

**Summary**

Overall, this example application yields indeterminate results. There is no way of knowing when the execution of `t1`->`t3` will occur. Having differing results is normal because the threads may get different CPU time each run causing them to progress farther or less far in their logic blocks. What we do know is that the `main` thread will ensure that `t1` and `t2` has finished before starting `t3`. Also that all threads `t1`->`t3` will finish execution before the `main` thread finishes.

Comment: @AbhiroopNandiRay If this answer helped you, please make sure to accept it as an answer to help future users understand as well!